Python: User input directories access
I wrote a python program to synchronies one of my source files directory. The program takes in user input of the directory to be used. When I run the code from within VS code, the program can access the directories.
I'm on a Mac, so this would be the one of the users input: /Users/dennis/Desktop/Phonenix Enigma Distro
But, when I try to run the program from a terminal, it can't find the directory. The code for the program is in my document directory: /Users/dennis/Documents/Python/Projects/Python backup software
Here is the code that takes the user input and then verifies the directory;
def Get_Run_Parms():
    # The program accepts run time parameters or user input.

    global line

    def Print_Help():
        # Print put help if need be

        os.system('Clear')

        print(f"SyncSource version {ver} Program help.\n")
        print("-s=<source directory to search>.")
        print(f"-t=<target directory to copy file to.\n")
        print("Example:")
        print(" SourceUpdate.py -s='source/directory' -t='target/directory'")
        print()
        print(" SourceUpdate.py -h   prints this help menu.")
        print()
        print(f'If no run time parms are present, the program will ask for user input.\n')

    # Check for run time parms
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print(f'\nNumber of parms entered: {len(args)} Parms: {args}\n')
    line += f'\nNumber of parms entered: {len(args)} Parms: {args}\n'

    # If 0 run time parms, ask the user for input
    if len(args) == 1:
        Print_Help()
        sys.exit()

    if len(args) != 2:
        print('No run time parms entered, please supply the following;')
        line += f'No run time parms entered, please supply the following;\n'

        # Ask for source, if no source, bow out.
        source = input(f'\nEnter source directory: ')
        line += f'Enter source directory: User Entered: {source}\n'
        if not os.path.exists(source):
            print(f'Source directory {source} not found.\n')
            line += f'Source directory {source} not found.\n'
            line += f'Program ended.\n'
            sys.exit(f'Program Ending.\n')
        else:
            print(f'Source directory {source} validated.\n')
            line += f'Source directory {source} validated.\n'

        # Ask for target, if no target, ask to create or bow out.
        target = input(f'Enter target directory: ')
        line += f'Enter target directory: User Entered: {target}\n'
        if not os.path.exists(target):
            print(f'Target directory {target} not found.\n')
            line += f'Target directory {target} not found.\n'
            a = input('Would you like to create this directory? ')
            line += f'Would you like to create this directory? User Entered: {a}\n'
            if a in ['Yes','yes','Y','y']:
                print(f"Creating directory {target}\n")
                line += f"Creating directory {target}\n"
                os.makedirs(target)
            else:
                line += f'Program ended.\n'
                sys.exit(f'Program Ending\n')

        else:
            print(f'Target directory {target} validated.\n')
            line += f'Target directory {target} validated.\n'
    else:
        for i in args:

            # Check for source, no source, bow out
            line += f"{i[:3]} {i[:3]}\n"
            if i[:3] == '-s=' or i[:3] == '-S=':
                source = str(i[3:])
                if not os.path.exists(source):
                    print(f'Source directory {source} not found.\n')
                    line += f'Source directory {source} not found.\n'
                    line += f'Program ending.\n'
                    sys.exit(f'Program Ending\n')
                else:
                    print(f'Source directory {source} validated.\n')
                    line += f'Source directory {source} validated.\n'

            # Check for target, no target as to create or bow out.
            elif i[:3] == '-t=' or i[:3] == '-T=':
                target = str(i[3:])
                if not os.path.exists(target):
                    print(f'Target directory {target} not found.\n')
                    line += f'Target directory {target} not found.\n'
                    a = input('Would you like to create this directory? ')
                    line += f'Would you like to create this directory? {a}\n'
                    if a in ['Yes','yes','Y','y']:
                        print(f"Creating directory {target}\n")
                        line += f"Creating directory {target}\n"
                        os.makedirs(target)
                    else:
                        line += f'Program ending.\n'
                        sys.exit(f'Program Ending\n')
                else:
                    print(f'Target directory {target} validated.\n')
                    line += f'Target directory {target} validated.\n'
            else:
                Print_Help
                sys.exit()

    return source, target

I'm new to python, so the program may not be up to a lot of peoples standards. So, what am I missing? Do I need to set the working dorectory to the root first? Am I inputting the directory incorrectly?

Make sure you've enabled Full Disk Access for Terminal in the Security system preference.

Are you passing the absolute path to the script?

This is what is entered: /Users/dennis/Desktop/Phonenix Enigma Distro.

@Barmar That was the problem. I gave terminal full access and it was able to find the directory! Thanks!
